# Calling specific index of Array in setter method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a class `Gs` with the following defined:

```
private static double[] r = new double[3];
```

I also create the getter/setter for this array:

```
public static double[] getR() {
    return r;
}

public static void setR(double[] r) {
    Gs.r = r;
}
```

In another class I want to set the value in the array, e.g. just `r[1]` but I don't know how I can do it with these functions.

How can I set the index of which I wish to set the value to?

```
r[0], r[1], r[2]....
```

The setter method expects an array arg `double[]` rather than `double` but I don't know how I'd specify it.

Comment: I suggest you learn when to use `static`. This seems like a case where it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the index as an argument to the getter and the setter:

```
public static double getR(int index) {
    return r[index];
}

public static void setR(int index, double r) {
    Gs.r[index] = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 double[] val = new double[3];
    //example values
    val[0] = 3.4; 
    val[1] = 24d;
    val[2] = 28.4;

    Gs.setR(val);
```

> Note: This will set the full array at once

Answer (score 0):

You just can set the the value on the array returned by the getter:

```
Gs.getR()[1] = .1;
```